# Formulate predictions of exponential growth and decay models using integration methods

Tags: calculus

I am trying to learn exponential growth and decay. But can find nothing to help me solve this.

My Question:

a) The instantaneous e.m.f. in an inductive circuit is given by the expression
 e.m.f. = 100.e-4t volts, where t is time in seconds. Predict what you expect
the curve of the graph for this expression to be and then draw the graph for the
using values for t from 0 to 0.5 seconds and compare your graph with your
prediction. Then find the value of the e.m.f when t = 0.25 seconds, and the rate
of change of when t = 0.1 seconds.

b) The expression i = 2(1 – e
-10t) gives the relationship between the
instantaneous electrical current (in amperes) and the time (in seconds) in an
inductive circuit. Predict what you expect the curve for this expression to be and
then draw the graph using values for t from 0 to 0.3 seconds at intervals of 0.05
seconds and compare your graph with your prediction. Then find the initial rate
of growth of the current I when t = 0 seconds and the time taken for the current
to increase from 1 to 1.6 amperes.

So far my answer for a)

$$P(0) = 100.e^{-4(0)}$$
$$P(0.5) = 100.e^{-4(0.5)}$$

Could anyone help or point me in the right direction to learn, and be able to complete these questions please.

Comment: For part $\text{a}$, just put in the values of $t$ to evaluate the emf. at that time instant. The rate of change at time $t$ is simply given by the time derivative of the function. $y=\exp(x)$ is a standard graph. Simply replace $x$ with $-x$, or reflect the graph about $y$-axis.

Comment: Have i the correct equations to do this above? Also how do i complete the workings out? I think i understand part b now.

Comment: The function $100\exp(-4t)$ has the derivative $-400\exp(-4t)$ and at $t=1/10 s$, this equals $-400\exp(-2/5)\approx-268.1280 \text{V}/s$.

Comment: Thank you. So above you have just worked out the rate? So can i just now change the t to 0,.25 and .5 to work the first part out?

Comment: Could you explain how you got your answer please? Everything i find online is about population not this.

Comment: Can anyone help?